# SASS Dynamic variable inside @for loop

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to dynamically call existing vars side @for loop in SASS.

```
$font-size-h1:            floor(($font-size-base * 2.6));
$font-size-h2:            floor(($font-size-base * 2.15));
$font-size-h3:            ceil(($font-size-base * 1.7));
$font-size-h4:            ceil(($font-size-base * 1.25));
$font-size-h5:            $font-size-base;
$font-size-h6:            ceil(($font-size-base * 0.85));

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  h#{$i} {
    font-size: $font-size-h#{i};
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot interpolate to call a variable with SASS. You best bet is to use maps, which work like arrays. Here's a good reference: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-sass-maps-usage-and-examples--cms-22184

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can: use **placheholders** instead of variables. It is a little bit more verbose than you think, but it works by using `@extend`:

```
%font-size-h1 { font-size: floor(($font-size-base * 2.6)); };
%font-size-h2 { font-size: floor(($font-size-base * 2.15)); };
%font-size-h3 { font-size: ceil(($font-size-base * 1.7)); };
%font-size-h4 { font-size: ceil(($font-size-base * 1.25)); };
%font-size-h5 { font-size: $font-size-base; };
%font-size-h6 { font-size: ceil(($font-size-base * 0.85)); };

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  h#{$i} {
    // Use extend to insert placeholder styles
    @extend %font-size-h#{$i};
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, technically you can... but why would you? It would be less code to simply write the classes.

Answer (score 0):

While @chriskirknielsen is right in his answer, he didn't really provide an example for how to apply it to the situation, so here is it:

```
$font-size-base: 16px;

$font-sizes: (
  h1: floor(($font-size-base * 2.6)),
  h2: floor(($font-size-base * 2.15)),
  h3: ceil(($font-size-base * 1.7)),
  h4: ceil(($font-size-base * 1.25)),
  h5: $font-size-base,
  h6: ceil(($font-size-base * 0.85))
);

@each $key, $value in $font-sizes {
  #{$key} { font-size: $value !important; }
}
```